# is there a way to drop all but alphabets and numberals from a string?

Tags: batch-file

I want to make sure if there might be a method to drop all but alphabets and numerals (and spaces) from a `%variable%`? hopefully without dropping each one but rather by choosing the characters to keep because that might be the easier task..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the string must be processed *character by character*. We may use an interesting trick that can separate each character in a string. The method consist in run a separate `cmd.exe` instance with the `/U` switch, so each character is followed by a binary zero. After that, use a `find /V ""` command to get each character-zero pair as individual lines.

Finally, just check if the character is in a `keep` variable, and ignore otherwise. The method also check for the special characters that can not be directly processed in a string-replacement: `!=*`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "input=Any ^!string#& /with ()=special*{ }characters..."
echo Input:  "!input!"

set "keep=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 0123456789"
set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cmd /U /C set /P "=!input!" ^<NUL ^| find /V ""') do (
   if "%%a" neq "^!" if "%%a" neq "=" if "%%a" neq "*" (
      if "!keep:%%a=!" neq "%keep%" (
         set "output=!output!%%a"
      )
   )
)

echo Output: "%output%"
```

Output example:

```
Input:  "Any !string#& /with ()=special*{ }characters..."
Output: "Any string with special characters"
```

Comment: I added `ä` and `ö` to the keep variable, but neither of those characters are not retained. What might be wrong? I am using `chcp 65001` at the start of my script, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Appearing you are trying to remove certain symbols or characters from a string, we can use a `findstr` with the `/V` switch to *exclude* those variables from the statement.

The problem with doing this, is it will see the charecter in the statment and remove it all together. To get around this, a series of for statments can break down the string and programmicly create a chain of findstar commands to automaticcly ban the charecters you want.

For example, the bellow command will take charecters from a `A,B,C,D` format and create a `^| find /V "A"` + `^| find /V "B"` + `^| find /V "C"` + `^| find /V "D"` string for each "Banned" character.

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%BAN%") do (
    set "output="
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('cmd /U /C echo %%a^| find /V ","^| find /V "*"') do (
        set "output=!output! | find /V "%%b""
    )
    set "B1=!output:~1!"
)
```

From here we can use this data and have it input it in another for statement to exclude those in the `findstr /V`. Keep in mind each block breaks each character on its own line to be added back into one later on in the block.

This whole process can be called to using a `call` statement with `%1`. In my solution all you need to do is Use `CALL :FIX (STRING NAME)` and it will go through, remove banned characters, and change that string to not have those characters.

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem | Banned character List (Must be in A,B,C format)
set "BAN=m,1,4,)"

rem | TEST strings we want to remove symbols from (Can be any name)
SET "STRING1=H$4jm)k@14+d^j"
SET "STRING2=money"

rem | Use (CALL) (:FIX) (STRING NAME)
echo BEFORE FIX: %STRING1%
call :FIX STRING1
echo AFTER FIX: %STRING1%

pause
goto :eof

:FIX
Rem | Create %1 into raw string & string data
set "VAR1=%1"

Rem | Create a Findstr for each banned character
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%BAN%") do (
    set "output="
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('cmd /U /C echo %%a^| find /V ","') do (
        set "output=!output! | find /V "%%b""
    )
    set "B1=!output:~1!"
)

Rem | Edit string without banned words
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!%VAR1%!") do (
    set "output="
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ('cmd /U /C echo %%a^| find /V ""!B1!') do (
        set "output=!output! %%b"
    )
    set "B2=!output:~1!"
)
Rem | Remove spaces & finish
set %VAR1%=!B2: =%!
goto :eof
```